# Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVEL DialectConfiguration:mvel

Tags: apache-axis, drools, mvel

I am using drools for processing rules. Web-service calls a method in a class which is in jar included in lib directory of web-service. And this method in turn uses drools. Now the problem is web-service is able to find jar that is using drools but not the drools-compiler jar which is residing in same lib directory. And it gives `Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.mvel.MVELDialectConfiguration:mvel'` error. It works if I copy all jars in `web-service.aar/lib` to `axis2/WEB_INF/lib`. I also tried to set classpath in a way to take `web-service.aar/lib` jars first then the one's in `axis2/WEB_INF/lib` by setting classpath in `setenv.sh` and catalina configurations. But that didn't help either.
What can be the reason/solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a newer version of the `mvel` jar. I added the `mvel-1.3.3-java1.5.jar` and it did the trick for me, but just remember to restart your IDE.